# plotting graph using two lists having string values

Tags: python-3.x

can you please help me by telling how to plot line graph in python(python 3.x preferably) using two lists containing string values.

my lists looks like:

> ```
> y= ['27%', '27%', '27%', '27%', '27%', '27%', '27%']
>
> x= ['18ww25', '18ww27', '18ww28', '18ww28.1', '18ww29', '18ww29.1', '18ww29.2']
> ```

moreover, there are multiple such pairs with different y list but same x list. Moreover x list should form markers on the X axis.

Moreover I am extracting these values from an excel file using pandas because of which I am getting values like "18ww28.1" although in excel file it is present as "18ww28"

how to plot a single graph containing all the lines from such pairs by correcting all x list values(for eg from "18ww28.1" to "18ww28") and then plotting.
If 7 pairs are there then the 7 lines should be there in graph and y list values should be plotted in the same format(in percentage)

the table which i want to plot is- [excel table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYz6N.png)

actually, this file originally conatins many tables. I have read the complete file in a pandas data frame then grouped this table then converted this table to csv and then iterated through each row by storing each row value to a list and have also stored 1st row value in a list and want to plot each row list against first row list in such a way-

```
row1_list=['18ww24','18ww25','18ww34'](for ex)


row2_list=['24%','25%','67%'](for example)
```

This basically means consumption of some resource is '24%' on '18ww24' thats why I have to  plot ('18ww24','24') as a point in graph(same for all the corresponding values of both the list)

then similarily,

> row1_list
>
> row3_list

and so on for every row......

Also, 1st row should form markers on X axis against  which every entry of other rows are plotted and the plotted line for each row should be on same graph

Comment: Can you provide a sample chart and corresponding values (x and y)?

Comment: edited the file.hope this will help...thanks